# Applovin MAX Facebook Bidding : Does it Actually Works?

Tags: facebook-audience-network, applovin

We have integrated Applovin MAX to use Facebook Bidding in our Andorid App. Since we have integrated & Tested The Integration, Under Test Mode FB Ads are Loading (when forced to show Meta Ads via Applovin Test Device Dashboard) BUT even then theirs a catch that in my FAN Dashboard I have set the Facebook to use real advertisers ads in test devices also. BUT Still Applovin Bidding with FB Serves FB Test Ad Only.

Secondly, We have tested the App in the devices which are not set as test devices in Applovin & FB, Then what we can see is that Applovin is showing it's own ads only. & We are Dam Sure that applovin can never provide better eCPM than FB, even then It Seems like Applovin Forces to Show it's own ads.

So here I am just to know if anybody is here who have used Applovin MAX for facebook Bidding & IF yes then please let us know that if it works well.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Experiencing a similar issue. Had the same integration with MoPub (before it was acquired by AppLovin) and it worked just fine. After transitioning to Max, it looks like FAN ads are requested but never shown. Maybe it's an issue with the SDK integration but I'm struggling to find it. Did you discover anything in the meantime?